# Where do NSLayoutConstraint objects live when activated with .isActive = true?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm new to Swift.
In an Apple development tutorial I found the following snippet of code

```
let button = UIButton() 
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:44.0).isActive = true
```

Can someone help me understanding what happens with the latter line?

`widthAnchor` is a *computed property* of `button`, and its type is `NSLayoutDimension`.

`constraint(equalToConstant:)` is a method of `NSLayoutDimension` class returning a

`NSLayoutConstraint` object.

Hence ... `.isActive = true` sets the `isActive` property of the latter object to `true`.

Where does that object "live" and how is it related to `button` object?

Thanks

Comment: The dimension presumably lives on the heap and is referenced by the consrint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView` and thus it has a `constraints` property that is `[NSLayoutConstraint]`.

The `NSLayoutConstraint` that you create is an object (so it is allocated on the heap) and a reference to it is added to the `constraints` property of the button itself:

```
let button = UIButton()

print(button.constraints)
```

> ```
> []  // empty array
> ```

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:44.0).isActive = true

print(button.constraints)
```

> ```
> [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000926b0 UIButton:0x7fbe6ff01940.width == 44   (active)>]
> ```

An `NSLayoutConstraint` is related to up to two items (views).
When you activate an `NSLayoutConstraint`, iOS adds a reference to that constraint to the `constraints` property of the appropriate `UIView` subclass.  The appropriate view depends on the relationship of the two items in the constraint.

```
relationship          add to
------------          ------
siblings              parent of the two siblings
parent/child          parent
single view           view
other                 first common ancestor
```

The first is just a specific case of the last, but I left it here for clarity.

---

**Siblings Example**

Here is a siblings example.  `button1` and `button2` are subviews of `container`, so a reference to the constraint that relates `button1`'s height to `button2`'s height gets added to `constraints` array for `container` which is their parent view:

```
let button1 = UIButton()
let button2 = UIButton()
let container = UIView()

container.addSubview(button1)
container.addSubview(button2)

button1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button2.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2).isActive = true

print(container.constraints)
```

> ```
> [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008ef10 UIButton:0x7f9ec7c03740.height == 2*UIButton:0x7f9ec7d06f90.height   (active)>]
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is a reference to the appropriate view object passed in the NSLayoutConstraint init, so that the constraints property of the view can be set to include a NSLayoutConstraint reference?

Comment: The NSLayoutConstraint init gets a reference to the two UIViews that are controlled by the constraint.  The system doesn't look for the common ancestor until the constraint is activated.  You can verify this by first creating the two view, and then the constraint, and then create the common ancestor, add the views as subviews, and then finally activate the constraint.  That works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Understood!